# SQL the identifier that starts with is too long in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sybase

hi i seem to be getting an error when trying to create this stored procedure. It was working on another Sybase database, and also on an oracle database, so not sure why it doesn't work now. I think I need to try to shorten the @tablename? but not quite sure how

```
CREATE TABLE #COMMODITY
(
    id numeric(10,0) identity,
    COL1 VARCHAR(10),
    COL2 VARCHAR(10),
    COL3 VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #TEMPCCY
(
    COL VARCHAR(10),
    id numeric(10,0) identity
)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_updateTT
(
    @tName   varchar(30),
    @colName varchar(30)
)
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @tablename  varchar(255)

SELECT @tablename = "UPDATE " + @tName + " SET " + @colName + " = t.COL FROM    #COMMODITY r, #TEMPCCY  t WHERE t.id    = r.id"

EXEC (@tablename)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: [Error Code: 103, SQL State: S1000]  The identifier that starts with '" = t.COL FROM #COMMODITY r, ' is too long. Maximum length is 28.

Comment: can you please give us a) the data server version and b) the client version you are using to connect?